# Receiving NULL data from POST on codeigniter

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter, post

I have this form:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-7 col-lg-5 mx-auto">
            <div class="card card-signin my-5">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title text-center">Cadastre-se</h5>
                <form class="form-signin" method="post" action="/caseMind/index.php/cadastroController/registrar">
                    
                <div class="form-label-group">
                    <input type="text" id="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
                    <label for="nome">Nome</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-label-group">
                    <input type="text" id="cpf" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
                    <label for="cpf">CPF</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-label-group">
                    <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-label-group">
                    <input type="password" id="senha" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                    <label for="senha">Senha</label>
                </div>
                <hr class="my-4">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-google btn-block text-uppercase" name="submeter" type="submit" ><i class="fab fa-google mr-2"></i>Submeter</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

In my View file, and then I'm trying to send that information to a controller function:

```
public function registrar(){

        $user = array(
            "nome" => $this->input->post("nome"),
            "cpf" => $this->input->post("cpf"),
            "email" => $this->input->post("email"),
            "senha" => $this->input->post("senha")
        );
        var_dump($user);
        $this->load->model('cadastroModel');
        $this->cadastroModel->salvar($user);
        $this->load->view('loginView');
    }
```

But var_dump() is showing me only NULL values, as if there was no information typed on the forms.
My insertion function (on model) looks just fine.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the **name** attribute in your fields

Replace

```
<input type="text" id="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
```

with

```
<input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
```

It should be done for all Input Attributes

Comment: That's it. You're my king zak